# IdentityResult succeeded is true when passing in fake roles

Tags: asp.net, f#, asp.net-identity

So if I pass in a role that doesn't exist into `userManager.AddToRolesAsync` the resulting `IdentityResult` object has a succeeded flag equal to true.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there's something that needs to be flipped in order for this to error out.

The example is I have a `user` role and an `admin` role. If I pass in GOD it will return `IdentityResult.Succeeded` equal to `true`

Is there something I'm missing?

(I'm using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`)

My expected result would be that there's an exception returned or succeeded equals false when passing in roles that don't exist.

```
let addToRoles (userManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>) userId roles =
    userManager.AddToRolesAsync(userId, roles)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.Catch
    |> Async.map convertIdentityResultToDUChoice
    |> AsyncResult.AR
```

Comment: Doesn't it just create a new entry in `AspNetRoles` when you do that? If so, I would just manually check if the role exists before calling `.AddToRolesAsync`

Comment: @VitorM.Barbosa I can verify that it doesn't create the role in AspNetRoles